# Firefox mysteriously stopped showing embedded Tableau viz on my Jekyll static blog site

Tags: firefox, jekyll, github-pages, tableau-api

I embedded a dashboard from Tableau Public in my static blog built with Jekyll and hosted on GitHub. I was tweaking the viz settings in Tableau, saving, overwriting the copy on Tableau Public, and refreshing the locally served site in Firefox to see the results. Was working fine for a while but then all of a sudden the viz disappeared, both for the locally served site and the live site at `username.github.io`. Thankfully, both local and live site display the viz just fine when loaded in Safari, Chrome, and Opera. But I feel the need to solve this Firefox mystery. The site is to showcase my portfolio to potential employers and I do not want to clutter it up with a disclaimer about Firefox.

Btw, I discovered the bug was browser-specific and not related to my code when I went back to [this tutorial](https://www.datavizforall.org/embed/tableau/) and saw that Firefox was not loading their demo embedded viz, which it had been displaying just fine previously.

Your insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That viz from the tutorial is showing up just fine on my Firefox on Linux. Can you disable all plugins and update Firefox and try again?

Comment: Ahh that did it! For reference I had PrivacyBadger and AdBlockPlus enabled. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That viz from the tutorial is showing up just fine on my Firefox on Linux. I think your plugins are causing trouble. Just disable all plugins and try again.

Comment: PrivacyBadger was the culprit.  Thanks!